# Facebook Chat Plugin Not Working in Chrome Content Security Policy Error

Tags: facebook, mobile, chromium, content-security-policy

I am implementing Facebook chat plugin in the site. But I am getting and error in Chromium browsers when I try to open the chat in mobile devices.

The chat is working correctly in Desktop browsers and Safari iPhone browsers.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
    <div id="fb-customer-chat" class="fb-customerchat">
    </div>

    <script>
      var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
      chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "000000000000");
      chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");
    </script>

    <!-- Your SDK code -->
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v13.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

This is my config

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-src 'self' *.facebook.com *.owneriq.net *.marchex.io *.doubleclick.net *.googletagmanager.com *.youtube.com *.google.com *.facebook.net m.me; frame-ancestors 'self' *.facebook.com  *.owneriq.net *.marchex.io *.doubleclick.net *.googletagmanager.com *.youtube.com *.google.com *.facebook.net m.me" />
<add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1;mode=block" />
<add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
```

This is the error in console when I click chat burble.

[Chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOtzh.png)

When I remove the Content Security Policy it works correctly. Am I missing something ?

Thanks.